# Spotfire: custom expression with dynamic column name

Tags: properties, spotfire

I have a cross table in Spotfire consisting of two columns. These columns show different values based on the document property 'PlanComparison':

[image]

However, I also want to give them a different column name, based on the property. E.g. like this:
[image]

This results in an error message though. How can this be resolved?